# gulp-plumber not playing nice with gulp-sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Having the following gulp file:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var args = require("yargs").argv;
var config = require("./gulp.config")();
var del = require("del");
var $ = require("gulp-load-plugins")({ lazy: true });

gulp.task("styles", ["clean-styles"], function() {
    log("Compiling SASS ---> CSS");

    return gulp
     .src(config.sass)
     .pipe($.plumber())
     .pipe($.sass())
     .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 5%"] }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});

gulp.task("clean-styles", function(done) {
   var files = config.temp + "**/*.css";
   clean(files, done);
});

gulp.task("sass-watcher", function() {
    gulp.watch([config.sass], ["styles"]);
});

function clean(path, done) {
    log("Cleaning: " + $.util.colors.yellow(path));
    del(path, done);
};

function log(msg) {
   if (typeof (msg) == "object") {
    for (var item in msg) {
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            $.util.log($.util.colors.yellow(msg[item]));
        }
    }
   } else {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.yellow(msg));
   }
};
```

The problem is that the `sass-watcher` is not finishing the tasks, which is the whole meaning of `gulp-plumber` I believe.

When there is an compilation error in the `sass` file, the stream is stopped with this configuration, with minimal error information:

If I change the configuration to **notice the difference in options for sass**:

```
return gulp
    .src(config.sass)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 5%"] }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
```

The task is finished properly and I get the following error message:

```
[15:50:22] [gulp-sass] error reading values after 10px on line 23 in     C:/Projects/ProjectName/sass/bootstrap-custom.scss
```

I would prefer the error to be handled by `gulp-plumber`, any ideas why it is not playing nice with `gulp-sass`?

I'm on a Windows machine by the way and using the `cmd prompt`

Comment: Seeing the same thing with Less and from the looks of your code i am walking through the same setup from JP. Using Webstorm 10 and terminal window within IDE on Mac. So I do not think it is your machine. Running through the tut right now now and added gulp-sass as well as gulp-less. Less works fine. But when I have gulp-sass as a devDep it snafus and does not work. Maybe plumber is just for Less. Going to try and remove gulp-less and just try with gulp-sass in my devDep and see if that works but had to uninstall package and remove from package.json to get it to work

Comment: Same issue. Plumber works fine with my JS files, but Sass errors require Gulp to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Plumber works fine for sass in my gulp setup.

Remove `return` before gulp in your task. That's what fixed it for me. I don't think it's necessary for any task at this point.

There are currently some issues reported with lazy loading. Verify that you are using updated gulp-sass and gulp-plumber with lazy loading turned off for gulp-load-plugins.

Also for your sass task try setting `errLogToConsole: false` so that it's not interfering with plumber. Plumber really is the better reporter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.pipe($.sass().on('error', $.sass.logError))` instead of `.pipe($.sass())`. It worked for me!